# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una petición POST con FETCH javascript? (solo texto plano)

Tags: api, fetch

tengo una situación. He estado buscando sobre como se utiliza "fetch()" de javascript, y como puedo hacer peticiones http. Lo que necesito es saber si existe alguna manera de mandar texto mediante POST, pero **sin usar JSON**, únicamente texto.

existirá algo como

```
fetch("http://url.net/iniciosesion",
{
method: 'POST', mode: 'cors',
headers:{
'Content-Type':'text/plain'},
body: usuario: 'CSM',
      contra: 'Pass'
})
.then(response=> response.json())
.then(usuario => {alert("ok")})
.catch(error => {
alert("Error", error);
});
```

`usuario` y `contra`serían los campos especificados para recibir los datos dentro del método POST

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres usar `text/plain`? ¿Vas a mandar un archivo de texto? Si es para mandar datos se construye un objeto y se manda como JSON, es lo más simple. Pasar a `text/plain` significaría escribir la información en un archivo de texto y pasar ese archivo. ¿Por qué quieres complicarte?

Comment: Hola. Este comentario es para el título de tu pregunta: consulta [FETCH API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) gran parte está en español

Comment: @quevedo
Si lo cheque, pero lo que pasa es que quiero enviar un dato sencillo desde un dispositivo. Pero el Servidor donde reside la API no es capaz de decodificar un objeto JSON, solo usa un POST simple

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo mando como JSON aunque en la API que quiero consumir no puede decodificar objetos JSON ?

Comment: Mandar los datos así no significa que el servidor vaya a recibir un json. Si tú mandas esto: `{ unaPropiedad : 'unValor'}` en el servidor no tienes que leer/decodificar json alguno, en `$_POST['unaPropiedad']` tendrás `unValor` . Realmente, mi comentario inicial no es del todo cierto, no mandas un JSON al hacer eso, sino un objeto. Ese objeto el servidor lo reconoce en el post como un array asociativo.

Comment: @A.Cedano. OOooh ya entiendo, muchas gracias

Comment: Ya entendí lo que tratas de hacer. Si es posible y es fácil. De hecho hace poco ilustré en una respuesta cómo hacerlo con javascript vanilla pero usando ajax en lugar de fetch **aunque en el fondo no hay gran diferencia** revisa: [R - Notificaciones en vivo con AJAX sin Jquery y PHP Vanilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/391028/91033)

Comment: @quevedo sabra de alguna forma de hacerlo con fetch API, ya que no va a ser algo tan complejo

Comment: Hola. Por las características de la pregunta, de momento, sólo te puedo pasar esta referencia: [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Ignoro lo necesario para preparar una respuesta decente y bien documentada.

Comment: @quevedo muchas gracias